# JQuery: Access all Select Tags that of of type multiple

Tags: jquery, select, reference, multi-select

I have `$("body select").method()` to apply the method on all select tags. How can I specify multiselect or single select with jquery? I am looking into something like `$("body select[multiple='single'")` and `$("body select[multiple='multiple'")`. How can I do this please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple:

```
var $multiSelects = $('select[multiple]');
```

For single:

```
var $singleSelects = $('select:not([multiple])');
```